# How Can I center a cclabelttf inside of a sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

So basicly i want to add some text inside a sprite and center it (Center it as in really centering it, no matter the size of the text)

[image: What I want]

[image: The issue]

[image: Here is with debugdraw]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set

```
myLab.position = ccp(mySprite.contentSize.width/2, mySprite.contentSize.hieght/2);
[mySprite addChild: myLab];
```

use this an enjoy...

Answer (score 1):

By default, you set position to the center of the label. Of course, if you did not change it's anchor point. So, this code

```
[label setPosition: ccpMult(ccpFromSize(sprite.contentSize), 0.5f) ];
[sprite addChild: label];
```

will place your label in the center

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both sprite and label have the same parent:

```
label.position = sprite.position;
```

Assuming label is a child of sprite:

```
label.position = ccp(sprite.contentSize.width * sprite.anchorPoint.x,
                     sprite.contentSize.height * sprite.anchorPoint.y);
```

If you modify the anchorPoint of either node it complicates matters. That might explain the offset you noticed. In the first case, I wouldn't modify anchorPoint for either node. In the second case you can modify anchorPoint of the sprite but not the label.

A common mistake is to use the texture's contentSize property (ie sprite.texture.contentSize) because that will give you the dimensions of the texture, which is typically a power of two size. For example an image with 100x200 dimension creates a sprite.contentSize with 100x200 but the texture dimension will be 128x256 due to padding towards the next nearest power of two dimension.

Btw, your example image shows an equal amount of padding above and below the font. This may be reserved space for "overdraw" characters or subscript and similar. This seems normal. This kind of padding doesn't affect centering the label as long as there's an equal amount of padding on both sides. The padding may also depend on the type of font you're using.

**Tip:**
Open ccConfig.h and turn on drawing of the bounding boxes by modifying this line:

```
#define CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW 1
```

This also turns on bounding boxes for CCLabelTTF despite the name. It might help you debug the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the debug draw hint. I have added a picture of how it renderes the text, and I can see it is not in the center, but how do I do that now when CCTextAlignmentCenter is deprecated?